# django south - stale user model when using AbstractUser

Tags: django, django-south

I am trying to get to grips with django and south, and I seem to have run into `stale contenttype` problem - and I am not able to find a fix for it on SO or google.

So, to start with I have a simple project on django==1.6 with the following on installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django_browserid',  # Load after auth
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'south',
)

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'
```

and I run a `syncdb` on this and do not create a superuser at this stage.

Now, I create a new app `loginapp` and create an `AbstractUser` as follows:

```
#loginapp/models.py
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    is_admin_enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True) # new field
```

and change the following on my settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "loginapp.MyUser"
```

now, on the login app, I run (I add `loginapp` to my `INSTALLED_APPS` dict):

```
python manage.py schemamigration loginapp --initial && python manage.py migrate loginapp
```

..all is fine so far - I can see that south has created the new User model on my db.

Now, I go back and do a `syncdb` on my project and I get:

```
The following content types are stale and need to be deleted:

    auth | user

Any objects related to these content types by a foreign key will also
be deleted. Are you sure you want to delete these content types?
If you're unsure, answer 'no'.
```

.. I am guessing django realizes that the user model has changed and the default model is now obsolete. I tried using "yes" here and I see the DB tables are still there - presumably because syncdb does not delete database tables.

How do I avoid the above problem in the first place? I just need the user model as defined in my `loginapp` and not the default django user model on my DB - using south.

Would really appreciate any clues/direction to solve this issue.

Comment: This is not a problem. It only means that auth | user is no longer referenced in the app (basically unreachable). South detected it and wants to see what you want to do with it. If you dont intend on using that anymore, it is OK to say `yes`. By saying `no`, the tables remain in the database, doing no harm.

Comment: I am not sure saying "yes" or "no" is affecting the outcome here. The tables remain on the DB irrespective of if you say "yes" or "no". `syncdb` cant really delete tables. I am sure there is a way to set this up without this `stale issue` popping up. Thoughts?

Comment: We are talking about south here. This has nothing to do with syncdb. Lets say you do a fresh install of the application, and a syncdb, these tables would never get created.

Comment: @karthikr: are you sure about this? I get the message when I run `syncdb` tho :(

Comment: Yes I am - Just successfully migrated from django 1.4.2 to 1.5 a month ago, and had a similar situation. One reason this could still be happening is, you might have some reference in the application which explicitly refers to "auth user" (may be a third party app ?)

Comment: @karthikr: what youve said makes sense - I do have django-browserid which relies on auth user - not entirely sure!

Comment: btw: the app is a new app - i.e not a `convert` app.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem using Django 1.7 migrations to migrate `auth.models.User` to `myapp.User` (that inherits from `AbstractUser`), and didn't want to wipe my existing production admin logs table entries that have to do with `User`, so I insisted on getting this absolutely right.

Assuming myappp.models is:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'
```

Here is what I came up with:

```
from django.db import models, migrations
import django.utils.timezone
import django.core.validators

MYAPP = 'myapp'

def migrate_func(old, new, apps, schema_editor):
    ContentType = apps.get_model("contenttypes", "ContentType")
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
    ct = ContentType.objects.using(db_alias).get(app_label=old, model='user')
    ct.app_label = new
    ct.save()

def forwards_func(apps, schema_editor):
    migrate_func('auth', MYAPP, apps, schema_editor)

def backwards_func(apps, schema_editor):
    migrate_func(MYAPP, 'auth', apps, schema_editor)


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ...
    ]

    database_operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(forwards_func, backwards_func)
    ]

    state_operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ...
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'auth_user',
            },
            bases=(models.Model,),
        ),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.SeparateDatabaseAndState(
            state_operations=state_operations),
        migrations.SeparateDatabaseAndState(
            database_operations=database_operations)
    ]
```